# ic_drawer icon stops responding as soon as I press the first item in the ListView of a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

So, I have this weird problem: I'm trying to use a DrawerLayout that contains a ListView for the slide-out selection component and a FrameLayout that will contain a specific fragment depending on the ListView item that is clicked. I have scoured the net for answers, I have read books and watched tutorials and I have finally managed to do just that in a way that I finally half-understand: great, you say! Not so fast!

I'm left with a tiny problem though that's making my OCD go crazy: the ic_drawer icon (the three-vertical-lines thing that responds to the sliding out and the sliding in of the drawer) stops responding as soon as I press a ListView item that loads a fragment, ie. it stays in the  "drawer opened" position (partially hidden in literal terms). I have tried using the syncState() method in various points in the code but no luck.

The code of the Activity that contains the drawer layout follows. Keep in mind that literally everything else works perfectly - it's just the ic_drawer icon that stops responding to the slide-out and slide-in state of the drawer as soon as I press a listview item and the relevant fragment appears:

```
package com.example.jsonbourne;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DrawerActivity extends Activity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ListView mList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private String[] listCells1 = { "Profile", "Messages", "Log In", "Register" };
    private String[] listCells2 = { "Profile", "Messages", "Log Out" };
    final String[] fragments1 = { "com.example.jsonbourne.ProfileFragment",
            "com.example.jsonbourne.MessageFragment",
            "com.example.jsonbourne.LoginFragment",
            "com.example.jsonbourne.RegisterFragment" };
    final String[] fragments2 = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle firebug) {
        super.onCreate(firebug);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        // setting up action bar

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listf);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
                .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listCells1);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };

        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int pos, long id) {
                mDrawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.frame, Fragment.instantiate(
                                DrawerActivity.this, fragments1[pos]));
                        ft.commit();

                    }

                });
                mDrawer.closeDrawer(mList);
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }

        });
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame,
                Fragment.instantiate(DrawerActivity.this, fragments1[0]));
        ft.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStates) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceStates);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }


        /*if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }*/

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.something) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Surprisingly, I haven't found anyone else that has the same problem, even after long Google search sessions.

Comment: Are you trying  to close the drawer and change the fragment while u click the list item?

Comment: Yes. I want the drawer to retract and the fragment to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener` twice, but expecting the original one to keep in sync. It looks like you want to swap each `Fragment` after the `DrawerLayout` closes. Here's an example to do that with the original `ActionBarDrawerToggle` you set up in `onCreate`.

**Set up a `Fragment` variable**

```
private Fragment mFragment;
```

**In `onCreate`**

```
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            ...
            if (mFragment != null) {
                final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, mFragment).commit();
            }
        }
```

**In `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick`**

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        mFragment = yourNewFragmentInstance;
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(mList);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. It also helped me understand the inner workings of the ActionBarToggle class better.

Comment: Plus, it made the code much cleaner and much more streamlined!